# Retrieving images using a file path stored in a sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a table in my SQL database that stores an AccountID and an ImageID -  the ImageID being a file path to an actual account image in .gif format.

What would I need to do is, to retrieve the image from the file path saved on my SQL database onto an image control? I am using asp.net in c#.

Potentially, when the page is accessed, depending on which account has logged on, the appropriate image specific for the account is retrieve (I would imagine I can set up an @AccountID parameter at a later date)

If anyone has example code for something they have done similarly, I would be most grateful for any pointers you may have.

Comment: I don't have the necessary expertise to propose a full solution to your problem but I would just suggest also storing the images in the database, in order to avoid access rights issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeCN"].ConnectionString;
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select imageid from accounts where accountid = @accountid";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountid", 5);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            var filePath = reader.GetString(0);
            // For this to work images must be stored inside the web application.
            // filePath must be a relative location inside the virtual directory
            // hosting the application. Depending on your environment some
            // transformations might be necessary on filePath before assigning it
            // to the image url.
            imageControl.ImageUrl = filePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Darin.

Sorry for the simple question but should I just include this in 'protected void Page_load' or should I stick it under 'protected void Image1_Load'?

Comment: Me again! - I am receiving "The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found.

I'm using system.data.sql.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Also, in your example What should be placed in ["SomeCN"]?

Apologies for the additional questions

Comment: You need to reference the `System.Data` assembly in your project.

Comment: thanks Darin - I managed to get that to work..ish...well it is firing but unfortunaterly the images do not pull through.

Do I need to amend the asp.image control to pick up the filepath or should this just display the image depending upon the account ID?

How would I amend the code above so that I could test this i.e. using Account 12345 ?

Thank you for your assistance, as you can tell, I am out of my depth here.

Answer (score 0):

Hai ,
Check this out...
In your aspx:

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="ImgUpload" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Upload_Click" />
    <asp:Image ID="samp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/new//Testingimages1253899911515.gif " />
</div>
```

In your aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private bool IsImage(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    if (file != null && Regex.IsMatch(file.ContentType, "image/\\S+") &&
      file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public string SaveImageFile(FileUpload fu, string directoryPath, int MaxWidth, int MaxHeight, string prefixName)
{
    string serverPath = "", returnString = "";
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = fu.FileBytes;
        //Int64 len = 0;
        prefixName = "Testing" + prefixName;
        //directoryPath = "Testing/";
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        string dipath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + directoryPath;
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dipath);
        if (!(di.Exists))
        {
            di.Create();
        }
        HttpPostedFile file = fu.PostedFile;
        DateTime oldTime = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan structTimespan = currentTime - oldTime;
        prefixName += ((long)structTimespan.TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
        if (IsImage(file))
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file.InputStream, false))
            {
                serverPath = dipath + "//" + prefixName + fu.FileName.Substring(fu.FileName.IndexOf("."));
                img.Save(serverPath);
                returnString = "~/" + directoryPath + "//" + prefixName + fu.FileName.Substring(fu.FileName.IndexOf("."));
            }
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}

protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imageUrl;
    imageUrl = SaveImageFile(ImgUpload, "images/new", 600, 600, "images");
    Response.Write(imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: add namespaces:

using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Answer (score 0):

Try these links it might help you..

you can also try by storing the image files on the server and store the paths on the Sql table.. by these links

http://pratikataspdotnet.blogspot.in/2014/11/retrieve-images-from-path-stored-in.html